# After restarting Terminal, I can no longer execute Node

Tags: macos, bash, node.js, terminal

For some reason, **after I restart Terminal, I won't be able to execute node anymore**. Trying so results in the following error:

```
-bash: node: command not found
```

I tried removing node and reinstalling it. That works, but as soon as I restart Terminal, the magic is lost.

**How can this be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could the magic involve setting the `PATH` variable so `node` would be on the path if so then add the magic to your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Had a meeting. This is what my `.bashrc` says: `export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH` Looks normal, right? Still, no magic.

Comment: what i meant was that the installation of node changed the `PATH` to include its location. so when `node` works what is the result of `echo $PATH` and `which node`?

Comment: `echo PATH` says `/Users/karimmaassen/local/bin:/Users/karimmaassen/local/bin:/Users/karimmaassen/local/node/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` I installed node 4.10

Comment: you should add `export PATH=$HOME/​local/node/bin:$PATH` to `.bashrc`

Comment: I did. Doesn't seem to fix it.  EDIT: I did, now it fixes it. :) Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It appears to be in the .profile where things got messy, by the way.