# Error when running Jugernaut

Tags: node.js, installation, redis, juggernaut

I just installed NodeSJ and Juggernaut (yes, and redis too) on windows server (64 bits)

It is not working ... It seems, by the evaluations, that is just install and run.

This is the error I get:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Node\application\juggernaut\server.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
```

Any one?

Comment: Because of no **optimist** module

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843338/persistent-cannot-find-module-errors-when-installing-juggernaut-in-os-x-and-ra

It seems to be a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under ubuntu 12.10 when I tried to run "nodejs server.js" after cloning the juggernaut git repo.

Eventually I installed juggernaut with npm ("npm install -g juggernaut") and now I can successfully run "nodejs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js" (path may depend on your npm module installation).